# Error on xmlParse - ColdFusion IIS 6

Tags: xml, parsing, coldfusion, iis-6

I've tried to find an answer to this for a couple of days but struggling now.

I have a coldfusion MX 6.1 application set up running in windows 2003 iis6. A few days ago trying to fix another issue I somehow managed to remove permissions mappings for various directories on the application, which after much sweat, I have given up on trying to restore.

My solution has been to duplicate the application and reconfigure the permissions under iis.

This has worked but when I now try to access the application it will no longer parse XML (RSS feeds).

The application has not been changed so I think this is a config issue in iis6.

The error is: `Next character must be ">" terminating declaration "%HTML.Version".`

But I think this is a red herring. I'm sure I had this issue when I originally deployed the application but I cannot remember what the solution is. Is it a MIME types issue?

I should also add that when I try to parse the files that are in the original site from the new site (i.e. I use port 8080 for the new site and port 80 for the old site) this also works. As soon as I switch old site off and change port on the new site to port 80 the xmlParse throws the error.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direct?

Comment: OK, you tell us an awful lot of stuff, but omit the critical bits: a) the code that's erroring; b) an example of the XML that it's erroring on.  That would help a lot.  One thing to try would be to just browse to the XML in a browser... it'll tell you if it's valid or not.

Comment: It was a very specific issue. I knew the XML was well formed because it had previously parsed without issue. Also the CFM file had worked without issue. 

I browsed to the XML file and it worked fine.

I've concluded that this was a flakey windows issue as I've carried out exactly the same procedure of copying the entire application and creating a brand new virtual site in IIS. This time it's worked with no problems.

I'd absolutely love to know why this problem emerged. To avoid the headache next time. But alas I doubt I will find out.

Comment: The thing is CF isn't going to lie. If it says the XML is bung, then it's bung. You need to look @ the XML that CF was receiving, and then having looked at it you'll see in what way it was bung, which - in turn - will help you work out WHY it's bung. There's not point in saying "it works OK elsewhere / other times", because that's irrelevant. That just means it *can* work, in other situations.  You're not interested in those situations, you're interested in this current situation in which it's not working. But, yeah, without being able to see what's wrong with the XML, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Unfortunately the info in the XML is too sensitive to post online. but is starts `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">`. I know about the leading white space issues etc. The routines and files are exactly the same, the platform is exactly the same, the only difference was that they were two sites in IIS 6. The XML files are really super simple RSS feeds. The error changed to `document root element not found` but was still referring to the same xmlParse function. I totally get your point about saying 'it works' but I can't even replicate the error now because it works.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot, you'll need to be able to manually run the function that parses your XML, and have a known working file that's erroring when you use it.  For ease, I'd make your XML file as simple as possible so as to not have to drill down in multiple parts of your file trying to find where your error is.

Start by removing all of your data in your XML file, leaving only your DTD and your first level data tag, which should be empty.  If that fails to run successfully, your problem is likely in your configuration settings; otherwise it's in your XML.

If it's in your XML, then start adding data back in, one level at a time, with the deepest drill-down remaining empty and run it again until you encounter your error; that would be the part of the file causing the problem.  If you can't see what the error is in your known-working XML file, than present it here and someone should be able to figure it out.